# radiobuttonlist selected value and its validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, radiobuttonlist, textbox

i have an form in which i have radiolist and set of text boxes and dropdownlist.now when i check an radio some textboxes will be disabled and some text box will be enabled .now i want to validate only the enabled text box and not the disabled one.
in the same manner when i check other radiobutton i want to validate the rest of the text boxes.can some body help please.

some one give me the validation code for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery then you can get the enabled text boxes using

```
$("input[type='text']:disabled")
```

and the enabled text boxes using

```
$("input[type='text']:not(:disabled))
```

If you want to use simple javascript then you can get all the textboxes, then iterate through them, check the `type` attribute for `text` and check the `disabled` attribute to `true` or `false`.